# URL Rewriting for the Default /First page of the asp.net c# website

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, rewriting

I am working on a web based application ,I am going to rewrite the url of the pages using Global.asax file .

I have successfully done all the pages but I could not able to do the first page of the application which is initiate while loading the application .

I have used below codes in global.asax file :

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetRouting(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private void SetRouting(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {


        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("log", "Login", "~/log.aspx");

        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Controlpannel", "Master", "~/Controlpannel.aspx");
        //routeCollection.MapPageRoute("QueryStringPage", "QueryString/{Id}", "~/QueryString.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary(new { Id = "0" }));
    }
```

and using below code while page loading :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("log", null));


    }
```

Please guide me what code should i need to write below page load ,My rest of pages are working fine with same code .

Regards
L

Comment: Anybody can you look into pls ,I will be very thankfull for that